# How to transmit data to client-side js file from the server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, express

I want to transmit my data to client-side JS file from the server, but right now the browser displays data on its main screen like when we use `innerHTML` property:

[image]

I have checked bunch of express.js tutorials but seems like there are no way to send (add, technically) data to the client side js file.

This is a diagram what I'm looking for:

> **[open the webpage] -> [(in server) get data from database] -> [send data to client-side js file]** -> // do stuff more in the client-side

Any tips to resolve this problem?

This is my code:

```
// Makes display the client-side html, temporary disabled.
// app.use(express.static('client'));

// Queries
const QUERIES = {
  prev: 'SELECT * FROM en.prevstore',
  curr: 'SELECT * FROM en.currstore',
  next: 'SELECT * FROM en.nextstore',
  samp: 'SELECT * FROM en.sample'
}

// Create connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password123',
  database: 'en'
});

// Router
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  db.query(QUERIES.samp, (err, results) => {
    let ternary = err ? console.error(err) : res.json(results);
  })
})
```

Client-Side HTML (request from the comment)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="quotes">
      should be filled as quotes of data from database
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      should be filled as color of data from database
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Client-Side JS:

```
function getWord() {
  fetch('http://localhost:4000')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(({data}) => console.log(data))
}
getWord() // I know it won't work but tried for just in case.
```

Comment: First of all, you have to call `res.end()` to close a request (if you don't use res.json(...)). Can you show your client-side code ? Do you want to inject data in the first response (that returns the html and js) or expose an API endpoint that returns a JSON ?

Comment: @Kornflexx Sorry, I'm a new guy about backend. I've never heard about both ways so I can't tell you what I exactly want it. (I added my HTML and JS on my post.)

Comment: You are using an endpoint: pretty common way of achieving data transfert between client and server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tried to load `localhost:4000` on your browser and it is requesting your `/` endpoint.

Your server has to return your static files (index.html & ...) on this endpoint.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
// public or any static directory containing your index.html, .js, images ...
```

Then you can move your `/` endpoint to something more explicit like `/quotes`

```
app.use('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  db.query(QUERIES.samp, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error', err);
      res.status(500);
      return res.end(); // closing the response /!\ IMPORTANT
    }
    res.json(results);
  })
})
```

On your client-side you will have something like that:

```
function getWord() {
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/quotes')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: It gives `undefined` on my client-side dev panel. I have only 1 server port (localhost:4000) and my dependencies are `express.js`, `cors.js` and `mysql`. Did I miss something on your answer?

Comment: My bad, I edited my post. In the network panel of dev tools can you see the json returned from the server ?

Comment: Yes, It is. With `localhost` and `index.js`. I can see the json data on the Preview panel.

Comment: Ok I just changed the last line of the promise on client-side, you should have access to data now :).

Comment: Sweet! You are literally my life-saver. Thank you for giving detailed answers.